# Літературні приклади вживання слова «люз»

Tags: значення-слів

В одному зі своїх перекладів я намагався перекласти слово *slack* і думав про слово *люз*. Я знайшов згадку про це слово на [r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B7&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on). Здебільшого воно там йде як переклад російського слова *зазор*. Хотілось би знайти якісь приклади літературного вживання цього слова.

Значення слова *slack* в оригінальному тексті:

Якщо у нас наприклад є нерівність

> 20 ≥ 2 x<sub>1</sub> + 7 x<sub>2</sub>,

то для кожної конкретної комбінації (x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>), наприклад `(1, 1)`, *slack* - це різниця між значеннями лівої і правої частин, тут це `20 − 2 − 7 = 11`.

От я й думав перeкласти це як люз, і зараз в сумнівах.

Answer (score 5):

Щодо вживання *люз*, я знайшов одне трапляння:

> Йому [на тому залежало](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1005/4) — щоб вони обоє зрівнялися: обоє одної породи, професіонали, і він не гірший (ба ні, ліпший — йому ж більше платять!), — щоб зник межи ними всякий, неперекладний твердою мовою, *люз*. Ось цей *люз* йому муляв. <sub>Оксана Забужко, [«Музей покинутих секретів»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2) (2009, Київ, «Факт»), [ст. 328](//books.google.com/books?id=klw0AQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C+%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9+%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B7+%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B2%22) (або [тут](//www.ukrlib.com.ua/books/printit.php?tid=2745&page=48)).</sub>

Як альтернативу, можу запропонувати відоме слово *[люфт](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D1%84%D1%82)*, що, здається, цілком підходить за значенням.

На захист слова *люз* можу сказати, що співзвучність з більш відомим словом на руку — якщо хтось не знатиме, асоціації прийдуть автоматично. (Схожість значень і форм навела мене на думку — а чи не походять вони від одного слова? Але ні, хоча обидва походять з німецької (перше через польську), але врешті-решт одне від прагерманського *[*lausaz](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/lausaz)*, а інше — від прагерманського *[*luftuz](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/luftuz)*.)